# is there any javascript library to resize images according to browser window size?

Tags: javascript

is there any javascript library for resizing the images according to browser window sizes ?

I need to consider all cases (vertical / horizonal image, vertical / horizonal browser window)

N.B. The image scale has to be the same! (no distorsions)

thanks

Comment: Using the browser's resizing functions or using *real* server-side recalculation of the image?

Comment: no only client side solutions. What do you mean for "browser resizing" ? I need an algorithm resizing the image accordingly to window height and width

Comment: @Patrick: He was asking, a browser distortion/scaling of the image, or the server actually returning a certain size :)

Comment: @Patrick: He means, using the browser's native resizing method, which varies from browser to browser (usually nearest-neighbour or bicubic), or using a server side method/ajax call to resample the image to keep it looking neat.  IE7 and lower use nearest-neighbour resampling which doesn't look very good.

Comment: ok thanks for explainations :) None of them. I want to have control over resizing it with javascript (and not let the browsers resize them differently) and I cannot use the server, because I don't want additional server calls, it has to be a client side solution.

Comment: @Patrick you need to be aware that you will be at the mercy of the browser and the quality of its resizing algorithms when doing this on client side: It's impossible to do custom image resizing in JavaScript in a performance-oriented way.

Comment: ok got it, i will just center the original images, but I sometimes need to resize them accordingly if they are too big

Comment: I've posted a solution code, what do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution. Is this insane in your opinion ? It works.. :)

```
var scale = 1;

                if ( imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                    if ( imageWidth > windowW) {
                        scale = windowW / imageWidth;
                        if ( (imageHeight * scale) > windowH) {
                            scale = scale * (windowH / imageHeight);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ( imageHeight > windowH) {
                        scale = windowH / imageHeight;
                        if ( (imageWidth * scale) > windowW) {
                            scale = scale * (windowW / imageWidth);
                        }
                    }
                } 
                } else {
                    if ( imageHeight > windowH) {
                        scale = windowH / imageHeight;
                        if ( (imageWidth * scale) > windowW) {
                            scale = scale * (windowW / imageWidth);
                        }
                    } else {
                            if ( imageWidth > windowW) {
                                scale = windowW / imageWidth;
                                if ( (imageHeight * scale) > windowH) {
                                    scale = scale * (windowH / imageHeight);
                                }
                    }
                }
            }





                imageHeight = imageHeight * scale;      
                imageWidth = imageWidth * scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but I used the "Supersized" jquery plugin in one of my projects (it offers diashow functionality, but if you pass only one image, it might be want you want): http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ There is also the "bgStretcher" plugin, seems to do about the same, but I havent used it yet: http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-jquery-stretch-background-plugin.html

Comment: yeah something like that, however the image here is temporanely cropped according to browser size.

In my case I always want to display it all, and scale it appropriately.